# SASS Nested Comments

Tags: css, sass, comments

I have a SCSS file looks like this

```
.seletor{

    /* comment 1 */
    .sub-selector{

    }

    /* comment 2 */
    .sub-selector{

    }

}
```

When I compile it, i am getting this

```
.seletor {
font-size: 8px;}
/* comment 1 */
/* comment 2 */ } 
.seletor .sub-selector {
  font-size: 8px; } 
.seletor .sub-selector {
  font-size: 8px; }
```

What i want to get it is

```
.seletor {
font-size: 8px;}

/* comment 1 */ 
.seletor .sub-selector {
  font-size: 8px; } 

/* comment 2 */
.seletor .sub-selector {
  font-size: 8px; }
```

So the comments must be the exact position that i wrote in the scss file. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be possible. I would wonder why you would want the comments to output like that? Generally speaking, the power behind sass is to allow your working document to be readable, and the actual final product to be compressed.

Some references:

If you're using compass, look at `line_comments`:
http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/

Which will give you an out put like this:

```
/* line 1, sass/file.scss */
.selector { font-size: 8px; }
```

Other wise, if you need to comment your working document, and don't want them to appear in odd positions in the output, use // instead of /* */

Comment: Yes it seems there is no way to do it. I need to add those comments because it is an html template and people will edit without sass. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the items in sass like this:

```
/* comment 1 */
.seletor{
    .sub-selector{

    }
}

/* comment 2 */
.seletor{
    .sub-selector{

    }
}
```

Then your comments will be respected without changing the position.
So it's only advisable for important comments and not for many.